# TextIOWrapper silently discards unflushed data

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io, buffer

If the stream passed to `TextIOWrapper` is closed before it gets a chance to flush to it during the deletion of the `TextIOWrapper` object, the data is never written to the wrapped stream.

```py
from io import TextIOWrapper
import os

fn = "/var/tmp/foo"
os.remove(fn) if os.path.exists(fn) else None
f = open(fn, 'wb')
tw = TextIOWrapper(f)
print(tw.closed) # False
print("blah", file=tw)
f.close()
print(tw.closed) # True

print("Contents of {}:".format(f))
with open(fn, "rb") as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

I know I should close `tw` before closing `f` in the code snippet. I also know that I know that the *Pythonic* way would be to use both the `TextIOWrapper` and `open` calls as contexts.

I see that `TextIOWrapper` doc agrees with the above observation.

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.del
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.closed

My question is: **isn't this silent truncation of data a serious bug**?

Python version: **3.7.4**

Comment: Why are you using `TextIOWrapper` in the first place?

Comment: @martineau To write native str (unicode) in Python 3 to a file opened in "wb" mode.

Comment: Why are you attempting to write Unicode into a binary file and why are you using the `print()` function to do so? I think this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am using `TextIOWrapper` to write polyglot code. This enables the users to write native strings in both Python 2 and 3.`print()` is used in some code I don't control.